# airflow ValueError: Not a valid timetable

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I am relatively new to airflow & currently running 2.2.3. When trying to set up a costume timetable I was getting the error :
`airflow ValueError: Not a valid timetable`

Following the discussion here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19578
I changed a line in the my version of the airflow/models/dag.py that you get on installing airflow.
I change the infer_automated_data_interval function as so

```
def infer_automated_data_interval(self, logical_date: datetime) -> DataInterval:
        """Infer a data interval for a run against this DAG.

        This method is used to bridge runs created prior to AIP-39
        implementation, which do not have an explicit data interval. Therefore,
        this method only considers ``schedule_interval`` values valid prior to
        Airflow 2.2.

        DO NOT use this method is there is a known data interval.
        """
        timetable_type = type(self.timetable)
        if issubclass(timetable_type, (NullTimetable, OnceTimetable)):
            return DataInterval.exact(timezone.coerce_datetime(logical_date))
        start = timezone.coerce_datetime(logical_date)
        if issubclass(timetable_type, CronDataIntervalTimetable):
            end = cast(CronDataIntervalTimetable, self.timetable)._get_next(start)
        elif issubclass(timetable_type, DeltaDataIntervalTimetable):
            end = cast(DeltaDataIntervalTimetable, self.timetable)._get_next(start)
        else:
            end = logical_date   # I added this to avoid raising the value error
            #raise ValueError(f"Not a valid timetable: {self.timetable!r}")  # I commented this out
        return DataInterval(start, end)
```

As far as I can see the jobs are now running on the expected schedule - but this feels like a very hacky and dangerous solution. Has anyone else had this issue?
What is this function supposed to be checking and why it's failing?

Thanks!

---

Comment: I recently ran into this same error, but upgrading Airflow from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4 fixed the issue for me.  I think [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20486) is the patch that fixed my issue - maybe check your error traceback and see if yours is going down a similar code path.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually on 2.2.3 as well and upgrading seems to have helped. I am now seeing a different issue. For the dags I have running on a custom timetable, if I try to mark a task as success the webserver goes into an endless loop of calculating the next run time/dag interval. Have you seen this?